# TTS Speech rate not working in few tablets in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have created an app that can read out mail that are received from gmail. I wanted to read the mails little compared to normal. Hence called speechrate with TTS as example below:

```
int spreechRate = 2.0;
talker = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
talker.setSpeechRate(speechRate);
```

This just works fine on my Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 10 and Samsung Galaxy tab 2 too but doesn't work with Galaxy tab (old).

Is there any settings that I need to check in Galaxy tab. For two tabs that are working I didn't check any settings at all?

Comment: can somebody help me out with this please?

Comment: Please do also add their OS Versions in question.

Comment: try to define float spreechRate = 2.0f;